# Определить максимальное количество соединений на ServerSocket

Tags: java

Как определить с помощью java какое стоит ограничение на количество открытых tcp сокетов (файлов).

Выбивает исключение `java.net.SocketException: Too many open files`, причина: соединений перевалило под 4096, не сервер версия ос.

Ос: Linux, Windows и тд.

Comment: Не по теме: Вы делаете что-то не так, если вам это потребовалось. По теме: знаю точно что в линукс это число в файлике, в каком -не помню, помню точно что это гуглится. По "too many open files Linux"

Comment: Да это для linux, а для windows(и тд), раз джава умеет определять как определить, если в итоге не найдутся ответы прийдется делать фикс ограничение.

Comment: Джава не определяет, ей прилетает исключение из ос

Comment: В тот момент когда проваливается попытка открыть новый дескриптор

Comment: Тоже об этом думал, но всеже найти количество макс соединений, мне требуется хотяб 1 дополнительное свободное соединение, чтоб просто принять его, отослать что сервер забит и закрыть это соединение.